# How to make entire tab section clickable?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am using [vertical tab](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-tabs/) I want the entire section clickable, but onclick is not working on hyperlink and icon image.

[image]

```
<li class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item" aura:id="core-tab" onclick="{!c.onHandelSideTab}" role="presentation">
    <a class="slds-vertical-tabs__link" onclick="{!c.onHandelSideTab}" id="core-tab" href="javascript:void(0)" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" >
        <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__left-icon">
            <lightning:icon onclick="{!c.onHandelSideTab}"  iconName="utility:settings" />
        </span>
        <span class="slds-truncate" onclick="{!c.onHandelSideTab}" >Core Settings</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Controllor:**

```
onHandelSideTab:function(component, event, helper){
   helper.setActiveTab(component, event,event.target.id);
}
```

Comment: Please, paste a bit of your handling of onHandelSideTab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need sooooo many on-clicks, so with the following code should be ok.

```
<li class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item" aura:id="core-tab" onclick="{!c.onHandelSideTab}" role="presentation" name="core-tab">
    <a class="slds-vertical-tabs__link" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" >
        <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__left-icon">
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:settings" />
        </span>
        <span class="slds-truncate" >Core Settings</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

JS

```
onHandelSideTab : function(component, event, helper) {
    switch(event.currentTarget.name) {
        case 'core-tab': alert('core-tab clicked'); break;
        default        : alert('unknown-tab clicked');
    }
}
```

Comment: but 'event.currentTarget.name' is not returning when clickin on icon or link

Comment: @Ragul, have you removed the `onclick` event from every element besides the one on the `<li`?

Comment: Yes, only on <li> but when i click on icon "event.currentTarget.name" is returinig empty.

Comment: @Ragul did you add the "name" on the li?

Comment: event.currentTarget.name is working! Thanks for asking, Your help is much needed for me.